# Method swizzling doesn't work for NSFileHandle class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code to do method swizzling:

```
static inline void swizzleMethod(const char *clsName, const char *mthName, const char *clsName2, const char *mthName2) {
    Class cls1 = objc_getClass(clsName);
    SEL sel1 = sel_registerName(mthName);

    Class cls2 = objc_getClass(clsName2);
    SEL sel2 = sel_registerName(mthName2);
    Method mth = class_getInstanceMethod(cls2, sel2);
    IMP imp = method_getImplementation(mth);
    NSLog(@"method type encoding %s", method_getTypeEncoding(mth));

    class_replaceMethod(cls1, sel1, imp, method_getTypeEncoding(mth));
}
```

My VGFileHandle class:

```
@interface VGFileHandle : NSObject
@end

@implementation VGFileHandle
- (NSData *)readDataToEndOfFile {
    NSLog(@"readDataToEndOfFile");
    return nil;
}
@end
```

In the main.m, I have the following calls:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    swizzleMethod("NSFileHandle", "readDataToEndOfFile", "VGFileHandle", "readDataToEndOfFile");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile"];

    NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
    NSData *data = [handle readDataToEndOfFile];

    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

By right, when [handle readDataToEndOfFile] is called, it should invoke readDataToEndOfFile from VGFileHandle and print out "readDataToEndOfFile". However, in my test project, it seems like the method swizzling doesn't replace the method implementation at all. [handle readDataToEndOfFile] executes the original implementation still.

I would like to know what might be the reason. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath] will return an instance of NSConcreteFileHandle, not NSFileHandle.

You need to call this instead:

```
swizzleMethod("NSConcreteFileHandle", "readDataToEndOfFile", "VGFileHandle", "readDataToEndOfFile");
```

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at the implementation of NSFileHandle, it is impossible to definitively say.

Most likely, it is because NSFileHandle is implemented as a class cluster and, thus, you don't actually have am instance of the abstract, public, class.  Instead, you have an instance of some private subclass (that may change for seemingly random, implementation detail oriented, reasons across OS releases or configurations).

**Swizzling methods is bad code.    Swizzling methods in private system classes is worse code and pretty much guaranteed to cause debugging and support pain.**